# Something's wrong when I use $.post

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Having some strange issue that I've been looking at for a couple of days now, and even with Googling can't solve.

I have this piece of JS that is called when a button is pressed. I cab tell this function really is called because the alert("1") pops up. I also know for sure the rarray is populated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function process_match() {
  var rarray = new Array();
  $x = $("input[name=pair]:checked").val();
  $left = $x.charAt(0);
  $rite = $x.charAt($x.length-1);
  $car1a = document.getElementById("car"+$left+"_"+$rite+"_1").value;
  $car1b = document.getElementById("car"+$rite+"_"+$left+"_1").value;
  .....
  $hsb = document.getElementById("hs"+$rite+"_"+$left).value;

  rarray[0] = $left;
  rarray[1] = $rite;
  rarray[2] = $car1a;
  rarray[3] = $car1b;
  .....
  rarray[15] = $hsb;

  alert("1");
      $.post("./updpoule.php",
    {'results': rarray},
    function(data) {
      alert("2");
    }
  );
}
</script>
```

Then, I have the following php file :

```
<?php
  $f = fopen("/tmp/q", "w");
  $array = $_POST['results'];

  fwrite($f,"AAA");
  fwrite($f, $array[0]);
  fwrite($f, $array[1]);

  fclose($f);
?>
```

I have seen this code all over as solutions to similar problems, but I can't get it to work.
If I run the code, the alert("1") pops up. After that nothing happens. No file /tmp/q is being created. BUT, if I debug the page, and set a breakpoint where the $.post is, and then step through, a file /tmp/q IS created, just not with the right content..

Any suggestions are more than welcome.

Thanks,
Hans

Comment: Your PHP never return anything, so the POST request just times out.

Comment: if you want to return any thing just echo that.

Comment: you also just assume that the fopen succeeded. never assume success. `if ($f === false) { die("Unable to open file for output"); }` as well, `$array` is undefined in your code, so you'll probably be getting a bunch of undefined var/index warnings as well.

Comment: @adeneo It won't time out, it will just return an empty string.

Comment: Open Developer Tools and go to the Network tab to see if there's an error with the AJAX call.

Comment: Update: just did a run with a breakpoint set, and the q file is created with the right content. So array is being passed to the php file. However, if I do the same without breakpoint and stepping through the function, nothing happens......

Comment: @Barmar: I opened network tab of developer tools, but not sure where to look. I do not see any errors when files are called, however I also do not see the php file being called.

Comment: Have you tried removing the quotes around `results` in the post request? So it would be `$.post("./updpoule.php",
{results: rarray},
    function(data) {alert("2");});`

Comment: @DustinPianalto Why would that make a difference? Quotes are allowed around property names, they're even required if the property name contains special characters.

Comment: I would also say, like @adeneo said, you should probably return something from your php script. Even if it is just a simple "Done" text.

Comment: @Barmar I wasn't sure if it would change anything. I just have never used quotes on them and all the examples I have found don't use quotes. So I thought it might be something to try.

Comment: @DustinPianalto Haven't you ever seen JSON format? It requires double quotes around all property names. And JSON is a subset of Javascript literal notation.

Comment: I test your code with fill the array with random values. Everything works fine. Are you sure your array is not empty ?
Is there something in your console ?

Comment: @Barmar nope, I have never used JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Try to return something from your php script.
For example, add this to the end of the file:

```
echo 'OK';
?>
```

And, in you JS:

```
$.post("./updpoule.php", {'results': rarray}, function(data) {
  if (data === 'OK') {
    alert('ok');
  } else {
    console.log(data);
    alert('error');
  }
});
```

If you'll get popup with `error`, check the console on the data you've got from php.

Comment: Thanks. Did exactly what you asked, but the issue remains. At the moment I do not believe it is a programmatic error but maybe something else. Without tracing and doing things step by step, I don't get a file, and neither ok or error alerts appear. If I trace and step into the function, a file is created and the ok alert appears. Strange...

Comment: Are you sure your function is triggered? Check the console for any errors.

Comment: Yep. When I trace the page and I click the button that onclick calls the function, the trace  stops at the breakpoint I have set within the function. If you like, you can see it in action at http://hanslammerts.servebeer.com/GPN/tools/invoeren.php

Comment: Ok, so I've tried the link you've gave it shows me ok-popup right after alerting '1'.

Comment: It does ? It gets weirder all the time. I can indeed see files being created, so everything must be working as it should. Except locally here, that is..Thanks for thinking with me. I'll try to do some more debugging to find out why it isn't working locally.

Comment: Update: the issue only seems to occur when I use Firefox. In IE11 and Chrome all is ok.

Comment: Yeah, the crossbrowsing always gives us pain :) I believe the JS code can be simplified. I'll try it later, when I'll have time.